# geoJson mapping with bokeh, wrong axes

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, bokeh

I want to map some locations which are stored in a geoJson format. The problem is that map axes (both x and y) goes from -2e7 to 2e7 instead of -180 to 180 (longtidue -x axis-) and -90 to 90 (for latitude -y axis-). Then, when I want to map my position `{"longitude": 48.90314,"latitude":20.70890}` I have to write `{"longitude": 4890314,"latitude":2070890}` otherwise it is located wrong in the map.

Does anyone knows why this happens or what I am doing wrong?

This is my python script:

```
    from bokeh.io import output_file, show
    from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON
    import json

    geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=json.dumps(geoJson_file))
    p = figure()
    p.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON)

    p.circle(x='x', y='y', alpha=0.9, size=10, source=geo_source)

    p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[
        ("name", "@name"),
        ("(Long, Lat)", "(@x, @y)"),
    ]))
    output_file("geojson.html")
    show(p)
```

This is the geoJson file (geoJson_file in py script) I want to map:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", 
                "coordinates": [
                    48.90314, 
                    20.70890
                ]
            }, 
            "type": "Feature", 
            "properties": {
                "name": "marker_1"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", 
                "coordinates": [
                   -94.91849,
           58.60959
                ]
            }, 
            "type": "Feature", 
            "properties": {
                "name": "marker_2"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", 
                "coordinates": [
                    81.03195, 
                    38.94440
                ]
            }, 
            "type": "Feature", 
            "properties": {
                "name": "marker_3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the map I get (but as you can see lon/lat is not the one it should be because I have to modify the lon/lat numbers from of the geoJson file (48.90314 to 4890314 and 20.70890 to 2070890) otherwise it is not properly located in the map)[image]

Comment: Looks like the map is in [EPSG:3857](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) ("web mercator") while your source is probably in [EPSG:4326](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). Is it feasible to pull in [GDAL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) as a dependency, which can do that transformation for you?

Comment: Thank you! you were right, the map is in EPSG:3857 and my data EPSG:4326!

Comment: So what did you do to plot it correctly?

Comment: I just transformed my coordinates from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857.